# API Gateway Authorizer is not being called

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, authorization, aws-api-gateway

I have created some Lambda Functions and deployed them using SAM. The deployment is successful, but when trying to reach the endpoints I always obtain

```
{ message: "Unauthorized" }
```

Even I'm sending a correct Bearer token using the `Authentication` header.
Then if I go to the Authorizer and run the test, it passes well and generates logs in CloudWatch, but when I run a request from my frontend app or a REST client app to the endpoint, I get the unauthorized message and checking CloudWatch, there's not an execution of the authorizer function.

Besides, checking the Authorizer function from the Lambda configuration, I can see that there's an error in the `API Gateway Trigger`, but don't know what it means.

I created the authorizer function using the guide provided by AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html#api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-lambda-function-create

Sharing my SAM configuration

```
Resources:
 SomeAPI:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      TracingEnabled: true
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: MyLambdaTokenAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          MyLambdaTokenAuthorizer:
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt AuthorizerFunction.Arn

  GetActivityStreamFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: get-activity-stream/ 
      Handler: index.handler
      Layers:
        - !Ref DepencenciesLayer
        - !Ref DatabaseLayer
      Events:
        GetActivityStream:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref SomeAPI
            Path: /activity-stream
            Method: get

  ## Authorizer Function
  AuthorizerFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Layers:
        - !Ref DepencenciesLayer
      CodeUri: authorizer/ 
      Handler: index.handler
```

Regarding the response sent back by the Authorizer, it sends all the params requested by API Gateway

```
{
      principalId: decoded.sub,
      policyDocument: getPolicyDocument("Allow", params.methodArn),
      context: { scope: decoded.scope }
}
```

The runtime I'm using is `nodejs12.x`, and here are some screenshots of what a I get from AWS console.

[image: Testing the Authorizer]

[image: Checking the API endpoint config]

[image: Error showed on Lambda console]

Comment: Could you try in API gateway under your /activity-stream route, to open the method request -> in the authorizer dropdown: select any other value (none or another authorizer) and hit save, then go through the same process and reselect your authorizer.

It should prompt you that it will re-add permissions to be allowed to invoke your authorizer function. This has worked for me before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of hours testing different things found by Internet, I started to have improvements when I noticed that the policy document was wrong:

**Before**

```
  const policyDocument = {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": effect,
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": resource
      }
    ]
  };
```

**After**

```
  const policyDocument = {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": effect,
        "Action": [
          "execute-api:Invoke"
        ],
        "Resource": [
          resource
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
```

Where `Action` and `Resource` should be arrays. Also I set the `resource` variable to be `'*'` instead of `event.methodArn`, because when caching the authorizations the policy cached matches only the first endpoints reached, while next calls to other endpoints result in the error: `user not authorized for the method requested`.

Other change was in the `template.yaml`

```
Resources:
  SomeAPI:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: MyLambdaTokenAuthorizer
        AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight: false
        Authorizers:
          MyLambdaTokenAuthorizer:
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt AuthorizerFunction.Arn
            Identity:
              Header: Authorization
              ValidationExpression: Bearer.*
```

`AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight` with `false` value makes the preflight calls (`OPTIONS`), to not be verified, because the preflight request are done by the browser, otherwise all the calls from `Axios` also fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing.
If the authorizer Lambda is not being called, I think it is because the auth is cached or the config thinks that no identity material was in the request.

Have a look at the https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_authorizer#identity_source setting: only certain headers are considered to contain identity material, and they are used as cache keys